# How to stop a computer booting into an operating system

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, iso-image, boot-partition

I have Windows 7 installed on many virtual machines, when it comes to rebuilding a machine, I load the boot iso, start the machine, log onto the console and press space bar to start installing windows.

If the machine does not have Windows already installed, the boot iso starts the install of Windows automatically, no need for confirmation.

Can anyone advise of a way of crippling the computer before hand so it forces it to boot from the iso, either remotely or by logging onto Windows before the rebuild and doing something?

Comment: What are you trying to acomplish percisely?  Please update your question instead of leaving comments.  You don't have to indicate you updated the question, just update it, the revision system handles everything

Comment: just destroy boot records of the OS installation you want "crippled" and rebuild them after you do whatever you want to do with ISO.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the boot order of your virtual machine(s)... for instance on Virtual Box you choose the 'system' properties of the guest and on the 'Motherboard' tab you can choose the boot order.

Either set it just before you boot the machine to hit the CD/DVD first... or leave it at that setting always and don't have a connected CD/DVD or image unless you want to boot from the image.

There's no need to cripple the installed OS... it just needs to be further down the boot order than the CD/DVD/image when you boot the machine to reinstall it.

(Edit... of course, if the Windows install image wants to drop you into rescuing the machine rather than installing... you could log on and format the disk of the VM (or remove all the files from it). But you'll still need to log on to answer the installer questions.)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Matt, the boot order is set to CD first, the prompt is coming from the iso, the iso is WinPE and was generated through SCCM, it automatically pulls files and answer all questions through a task sequence. but if the iso senses an operating system is already installed, it prompts to press a key in 10secs to run, which stops an installing loop when the machine reboots, i need a method to cripple the os really